# Show that the equation $x^2+y^2+z^2=2xyz$ has no integer solutions except $x=y=z=0$ using modular arithmetic

Tags: elementary-number-theory, modular-arithmetic

(a) Using modular arithmetic Show that the equation  $$x^2+y^2+z^2=2xyz$$
has no integer solutions except $x=y=z=0$

(b) Using the results in part (a), show that the equation $$x^3+2y^3+4z^3=0$$ has no integer solutions except $x=y=z=0$

What i tried

For part (a),

At least one of x,y,z is odd.
Can it be even? Reduce mod 4

$(even)^2=0 (mod 4)$
$(odd)^2=1 (mod 4)$

implies that LHS = 2 (mod 4)

all 3 are even ie, $x=2x_{1}$, $y=2y_{1}$, $z=2z_{1}$
implies that $$4x_{1}^2+4y_{1}^2+4z_{1}^2$$

(b) I have to somehow reduce the equation of part(b) to something similar to that of part(a).

Equation of part (b)
                         $$x^3+2y^3+4z^3=0$$ 
removing the $x,y,z$ term, we have 
                         $$x^2+2y^2+4z^2=0$$ 
and since $x^2$ is even, $x$ is even we have $x=2a$, doing the same for $y$, $y=2b$ and $z$, $z=2c$ we have,the equation

$$(2a)^2+2*(2b)^2+4*(2c)^2=0$$,
However im unsure of how to continue from here, could anyone help me with this question, especially part (b). Thanks

Comment: In part (a) all even then LHS is 0 mod 4, and RHS is also. That doesn't rule out that case. Not immediately anyway...

Comment: The second part is addressed [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2083504/show-that-x32y34z3-0-has-no-non-trivial-solutions-without-using-infinite).

Comment: The first part is addressed [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1851751/prove-that-x2y2z2-2xyz-has-no-answer-over-bbbn)